# Visual Studio 2022 Team Explorer not showing Azure DevOps organization for a specific user

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2022

We have an azure cloud hosted organization used by our developement team. I have one user, who's visual studio isn't able to correctly connect to our organization.
For most user's when using the Team Explorer, and selecting manage connections, https://dev.azure.com is shown with a child tree node for our organization. For one user, that child tree node is not present. There are 2 other child tree nodes present which were organizations added by this user via a web browser when the user was signed in with his company email. These two organizations were test organizations, and have since been removed via a web browser.

This user can use a web browser and can see our organization and navigate to projects he is a member of. The user is listed as a user in the organization settings as a Visual Studio Professional Subscription access level.
The user has since deleted the two test organizations from dev.azure.com so that only our company organization shows in a web browser. However, Visual Studio team explorer continues to show these two test organizations and does not show our company organization.

Another symptom: When the user attempts to clone a repository through visual studio, they are prompted 3 times to connect with a dialog that has the microsoft account associated with the user's company email and after the third request to select a user, a git password request dialog is displayed. This same behavior is seen when the user uses the Visual Studio Manage NuGet packages dialog and attempts to browse an organization NuGet feed.
The user is able to clone projects using a command line.

Is there a way to clear the visual studio team explorer cache and get this user connected to our organization?

We tried removing the test organizations.
We tried using the Add Azure DevOps Server selection from the Connect to a Project dialog. When we enter the dev.azure.com/ we get an error message "To access an Azure DevOps account, log in using the picker above."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the user had two Microsoft accounts, one was an older personal account which was tied to an MSDN subscription and is still assocated with the Visual Studio Professional subscription. The other account is a "work" account. Both used the same email.

To get our organization to show up in the Visual Studio connect to a project dialog, the user had to sign in with the personal Microsoft account.